# Is it possible to retain the datatype of individual numpy arrays with concatenation

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]) 
a = np.reshape(a,(1,6))
b = np.array([[1,2.1],[3.5,4],[5,6.8]])
b = np.reshape(b,(1,6))
c = np.concatenate((a,b))
```

When I concatenate the arrays a and b with **np.concatenate**. I get an array of type float. Is it possible to retain the datatype of the resulting arrays after concatenation?

Comment: Using NumPy version 1.11.1, I find the array `c` has integer dtype when I execute those lines of code. Which version of NumPy are you using?

Comment: Array `c` is `np.int64` for me using numpy 1.11.1

Comment: Double check the dtype for `a` and `b`.

Comment: np.int64 for numpy version 1.8

Comment: @ajcr I have edited the question. please check the question again.. The array b is of float type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mixed types... If I have read you correctly you essentially want to pair the values from 'a' and 'b'.  If that is the case, you can flatten your input arrays and reassemble them while retaining the appropriate dtype.  This is one approach, shown verbosely so you can alter the format if you want to construct it differently.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
a = a.flatten()
b = np.array([[1, 2.1], [3.5, 4], [5, 6.8]])
b = b.flatten()
dt = a.dtype.descr + b.dtype.descr
c = np.array(list(zip(a, b)), dtype=dt)
frmt = """
:Array 'a'... {}
:Array 'b'... {}
:Combined dtype ... {}
:Resultant structured array...
{!r:}
:Viewed column-wise
{!r:}
:
"""
print(frmt.format(a, b, dt, c, c.reshape(c.shape[0], 1)))
```

output

```
:Array 'a'... [1 2 3 4 5 6]
:Array 'b'... [ 1.000  2.100  3.500  4.000  5.000  6.800]
:Combined dtype ... [('', '<i8'), ('', '<f8')]
:Resultant structured array...
array([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.1), (3, 3.5), (4, 4.0), (5, 5.0), (6, 6.8)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
:View column-wise
array([[(1, 1.0)],
       [(2, 2.1)],
       [(3, 3.5)],
       [(4, 4.0)],
       [(5, 5.0)],
       [(6, 6.8)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
:
```

As an alternative to all that, you can exploit some optional tools from
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py

```
from numpy.lib import recfunctions as rfn
a0 = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]])
b0 = np.array([[1, 2.1],[3.5, 4],[5, 6.8]])
d = rfn.merge_arrays((a0, b0), flatten=True, usemask=False, asrecarray=False)
```

Yielding...

```
>>> c
array([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.1), (3, 3.5), (4, 4.0), (5, 5.0), (6, 6.8)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
>>> d
array([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.1), (3, 3.5), (4, 4.0), (5, 5.0), (6, 6.8)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8')])
>>> c == d
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=bool)
```

EDIT
Based on your comments, it appears you need to consider how you really want to keep the data together.  An array with a dtype of 'object' is possible, but probably not very useful...possible, but not the best way of organizing it.  Consider saving to a *.npz format instead, if your intent is for archiving.  In any event...

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> b = np.arange(9.).reshape(3,3)
>>> c = np.array(["array a", "array b"])
>>> d = np.array([a,b,c], dtype='object')
>>> d
array([array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]]),
       array([[ 0.000,  1.000,  2.000],
       [ 3.000,  4.000,  5.000],
       [ 6.000,  7.000,  8.000]]),
       array(['array a', 'array b'], 
      dtype='<U7')], dtype=object)
```

Comment: i dont want to pair them... if a = [1, 2, 3] and b = [3, 2.4, 5.88], then the output of concatenation should be [1, 2, 3, 3, 2.4, 4, 5.88]. while what i m getting is [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.4, 4.0, 5.88]   
will this be possible ?

Comment: you can't have mixed and get anything useful...a = np.array([1, 2, 3]); b = np.array([3, 2.4, 5.88])
>>> c = np.array([a,b], dtype='object')
>>> c
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3.0, 2.3999999999999999, 5.8799999999999999]], dtype=object)   The repeating 999s are floating point representation and the dtype is object.  Perhaps, you need to elaborate as to why you need to mix floats with ints in the first place

Comment: I am creating a a dataset . it will have 2 images and a label in coloumn major form. Images are having int values, While the label matrix can have decimal values. so i need to store them all together and keep the type intact., one after the other and extract accordingly. i dont know if that is possible. i am a newbie with numpy.